# C language: Given a string, delete/remove the words that contain the n number of vowels

Tags: c, string, function

Given an integer `n`, the program has to delete each word, that contains the `n` number of vowels.
The string is read from a test.txt file, which contains the following:
`Astazi nu este maine`.
Currently my program contains a `count1` function, that counts the number of characters and vowels for each word in the string.
How can I use the data from `count1` function as a refference when typing in the `n` vowels to delete the needed words then print the updated string?

I have an idea, which I'm unsure how to implement. In `count1` we already count the number of vowels per each word, so, given `n` by the user we check if this number is equal to `v` in the `count1` function and so we do `int num_of_words++`, then we do a loop, which prints out the needed words, until `num_of_words=0`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void count1 (char* str)
{
    for (int i = 0;;)
        for (int v = 0, w = i;;)
        {
            int len;
            char c = str[i++];
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                v++;
            default:
                continue;
            case ' ':
            case '\t':
            case '\n':
            case '\0':
                len = i - 1 - w;
                printf("'%.*s': %d characters, %d vowels\n", len, str+w, len, v );
                if (c)
                    break;
                else
                    return;
            }
            break;
        }
}

void count2 (char* str, int n)
{
    char line2[128];
    int ls=strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0;;)
        for (int v = 0, w = i;;)
        {
            int len;
            char c = str[i++];
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                v++;
            default:
                continue;
            case ' ':
            case '\t':
            case '\n':
            case '\0':
                for(int k = 0; str[k] != '\0'; k++)
                {
                    if (k == 0 || isspace(str[k]))
                    {
                        if(v==n)
                        {
                            strcat(line2, str+1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                printf("%s ", line2);
                if (c)
                    break;
                else
                    return;
            }
            break;
        }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[128];
    int c=0, count[26]= {0}, x;
    int n;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", line);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s\n\n", line);

    while (line[c] != '\0')
    {
        if (line[c] >= 'a' && line[c] <= 'z')
        {
            x = line[c] - 'a';
            count[x]++;
        }
        c++;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
    {
        printf("%c occurs %d times.\n", c + 'a', count[c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    count1(line);
    printf("\nInsert n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    count2(line, n);



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my final solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void count1 (char* str)// count numbers of vowels for each word
{
    for (int i = 0;;)
        for (int v = 0, w = i;;)
        {
            int len;
            char c = str[i++];
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                v++;
            default:
                continue;
            case ' ':
            case '\t':
            case '\n':
            case '\0':
                len = i - 1 - w;
                printf("'%.*s': %d characters, %d vowels\n", len, str+w, len, v );
                if (c)
                    break;
                else
                    return;
            }
            break;
        }
}

void print_x(char* str, int n)
{
    char* tmp;
    unsigned int cnt = 0, stat = 0;
    const char aeiou[] = "AEIOUaeiou";
    while(*str)
    {
        switch(stat)
        {
        case 0://the word did not start
            if (!isalpha(*str))
            {
                putchar(*str);
                break;
            }
            stat = 1;
            tmp = str;
            cnt = 0;
        case 1://the word started
            if (strchr(aeiou, *str))
            {
                cnt++;
                break;
            }
            if (! isalpha(*str))
            {
                if (cnt != n)
                while(tmp <= str) putchar(*(tmp++));
                else putchar(*str);
                stat = 0;
            }
        } // end switch
        ++str;
    }
    if (stat)
    {
        --str;
        if (cnt != n) while(tmp <= str) putchar(*(tmp++));
    }
}


int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[128], line2[128];
    int c=0, count[26]= {0}, x;
    int n,a;
    int i,j;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", line);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s\n\n", line);

    while (line[c] != '\0')
    {
        if (line[c] >= 'a' && line[c] <= 'z')
        {
            x = line[c] - 'a';
            count[x]++;
        }
        c++;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
    {
        printf("%c occurs %d times.\n", c + 'a', count[c]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 26; ++j)
        {
            if (count[i] < count[j])
            {
                a = count[i];
                count[i] = count[j];
                count[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
    {
        printf("%c occurs %d times.\n", c + 'a', count[c]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    count1(line);
    printf("\nInsert n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (!(fp = fopen("./test.txt", "r")))
    {
        printf("unable open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(line, 128, fp))
        print_x(line, n);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string `str` that consists of separate words, separated one from another by `' '` or `'\n'` or `'\t'`, and you want to have a string that contains all the words in `str` that satisfy some condition, it will be a bit difficult to program it such that it will be "in-place", i.e. to change `str` to the desired string, without using a "helper array" of some sort.

Instead, I would recommend to create a new char array with the same size (say `str2`), and every time you find a word that satisfies the condition (the condition can be for example: doesn't have 1 vowel), you copy the word that you found from `str` to `str2`.

Something like this:

```
char str[128];
// read from file to str using fscanf
char str2[128];
for (int c = 0; str[c] != '\0'; ++c)
{
   if (c == 0 || isspace(str[c]))
   {
      if (! is_1_vowel[str+1]) // if it doesn't have exacly one vowel
      {
          // copy the word from str to str2
          strcat_word(str2, str+1); // a user-defined adapted version of strcat that will copy from src to dest only till src reaches a space character or '\0'
      }
   }
}
```

I'm assuming here that `is_1_vowel` will be a function that goes over a single word (and not the whole line or file), and returns 1 if it satisfies the condition (has 1 vowel), and returns 0 otherwise.

Comment: i've tried to use your idea, but i've changed the `if (! is_1_vowel[str+1])`  to `if(v==n)`, but it keeps on deleting the first letter of my string and that's it. Why `v==n`, well, `v` is the number of vowels  and `n` is the number inserted by user and i've put that in a second `count2` function, that it's basically the same, but without the printf and with your code in it

Comment: you could check the description, I've updated it